# I have a problem with winform stock management program

Tags: c#, excel, database, winforms, winforms-interop

So i am making a winform stock management program but i am a beginner it is almost complete i just need to add the necessary textboxes and buttons.
But I have a Problem,
Just to make sure that everything is good i compiled it and i run it but instead of 1 data table I have 2
the first table is the one i created in the form designer but it doesnt import the data it was supposed to import from an excel file
The second table i did not create but it came it has three columns
and the second table has the information from the excel file
The Problem is my excel file contains 16 columns

I tried asking CHATGPT since i am a beginner. it said there were no errors

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.